# can anyone help me, how to move fragmnet to activity

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I use a fragment from HomeFragment to TanamanActivity, I don't use intents because I don't really understand, can anyone help me with the sample code below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val tanamanActivity = TanamanActivity()
    val personFragment = PersonFragment()


    makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
    bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.ic_home -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.ic_tanaman -> tanamanActivity
            R.id.ic_person -> makeCurrentFragment(personFragment)
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun makeCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.fl_wrapper, fragment)
        commit()
    }
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx6yG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Intent to start a new activity. Sample code:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, TanamanActivity::class.java))
```

**Intent** construtor takes 2 arguments:

1. **Context** in which **Intent** will be used (in that case your **HomeActivity**)
2. **Class** of the component that will be used for the intent (in that case **TanamanActivity** class)

Comment: is it like that ?

Comment: `val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
val tanamanActivity = TanamanActivity()
val personFragment = PersonFragment()
startActivity(Intent(this, TanamanActivity::class.java))`

Comment: @HafidSuhanizar you should not to create the activity instance with the constructor. Use my code in your NavigationItemSelectedListener instead of **tamacanActivity**.

Comment: `R.id.ic_home -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                R.id.ic_tanaman -> startActivity(Intent(this, TanamanActivity::class.java))
                R.id.ic_person -> makeCurrentFragment(personFragment)`

Comment: is it like that ?

Comment: the error moved to the splashscreen **at org.d3ifcool.agromap.fragment.SplashScreenFragment$onCreateView$1.run(SplashScreenFragment.kt:22)**

Comment: `if (onBoardingFinished()){
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashScreenFragment_to_homeActivity)`